# Ti*k*Z, automata: Change decoration of initial state?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I'm partial to marking the initial state of my automata with a '>' (somewhat larger) pointing at the state. I find the "initial -->" distracting. Is there any way to change the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just decrease the `initial distance` and use `arrows.meta` to add a largish arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every initial by arrow/.style={-{Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=6pt]}},
    initial distance=0.01cm,initial text={}]
\node[state,initial] {$q_0$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fooling around before seeing your answer I came to essentially the same solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This may interest you -- from the pgf manual chapter on decoration.markings at page 646 --

link--> http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

[image]

Position and color can be adjusted as per your choice  -- this is only a rough draft

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, decorations.shapes, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, decoration={shape= isosceles triangle, shape 
  width=0.65cm, shape height=0.45cm,shape sep=0.75cm,shape backgrounds}]
  \node[state] (q_0) {$q_0$};
  \draw[decorate, fill=red] (-2cm,0)-- node[above]{start} (q_0);
  \draw [decorate, fill=red](1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `every initial by arrow` style and fix `scale` and `line width` options.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows.meta, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[initial text = {}, initial distance = {0.01mm},
     every initial by arrow/.style = { -{To[scale=2.0, line width=0.7pt]}  }]
%
        \node (q0) [state, accepting, initial] {$q_{0}$};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: DFA]

See [PGF/TikZ manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.5) for more arrow tips.